# Causation vs correlation problem in case of fixing other parameters and changing only one

Tags: statistics, correlation, data-analysis

I have a game that players play. D7 retention is defined as percentage of players who installed my game and after exactly 7 days later they played my game.

Now I am doing analytics and it shows that only 10% of players play my game on day 7. I change the difficulty of the game significantly and collect analytical data. Data shows that now D7 is 15%.

Can I conclude that D7 change is caused by difficulty change or this is one of the examples that correlation is not causation? And how I can identify if I can think of causation or not.

Physicists, psychologists in experiments have done a lot such things. Fixing all parameters changing one and observing the behavior change and drawing conclusion. What is the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of causality is a little tricky. You can (usually) not test for that. You need to come up with a theory-based idea of how things work, such as if the price for a good goes up, demand goes down. And in empirical applications you need to think about, what other things influence demand, so that you don't omit important aspects of the data generating process.

When I read your description, it seems that you might have a good chance to isolate the causal effect of the change in difficulty. This seems to be a classical example for "[difference-in-difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences)" (DiD). The only problem may be that you changed the diffculty for *all* players, so you need to see how to handle this.

Another thing that comes to my mind is, that you essentially look at survival rates (after X days), this would be a task for "[survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).

As a (more or less) naive approach, I would say that your approach goes in the right direction. However, make sure that you control for anything you can, like player characteristics (because it is possible that now different people play your game compared to the past).

So when you have

$$y = \beta X + \gamma d + u$$,

where $y$ is D7, $X$ is anything you know about players, and $d$ is difficulty (0 diffcult, 1 less difficult), you should get a more or less good idea, what changing $d=0$ to $d=1$ does to y. When you use OLS (linear regression), the coefficient $\gamma$ should directly give you the change. But remember, this is a more or less naive approach (which should give "okay" results).

Comment: Oh man, thank you for the answer. By reading this I came to conclusion that there are lots of concepts that I need to study first.

Comment: It‘s a bottomless pit